# How i can stop the domain use for send SPAM

Tags: email, cpanel, spam-prevention

I have an account in CPANEL and i can see that in the last two days a email with my domain (This email don't exist in my cpanel email accounts) beging to send emails.

How i can to stop it? what i can do?